# Using StreamReader to determine if File has been changed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am curious. If I am using a combination of streamreader and streamwriter is there a way that I can have a stream written only if File X has been modified?

This code may not be constructed in the best way. It is attached to help in getting my questions accross.

```vb
sCommand = "whoami.exe >> C:\Desktop\Test.txt"

Using swrr As New StreamWriter(File.Open(ErrorLog, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            For Each strUserName As String In strLines
                Shell("cmd.exe /c" & sCommand, AppWinStyle.Hide, True, )
                'command Cannot Execute, List Why and Move onto Next Command
                Using sr As New StreamReader(File.Open(Test.txt, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    If '''??File has been modifed??''''' Then swrr.WriteLine("PASS") Else swrr.WriteLine("FAIL")
                End Using
            Next
  End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `File.ReadAllText(path)` to get a string containing the text.

You can then compare the new string to the old one.

---

The correct way to read the output of a command is to use the [`Process` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) with `RedirectStandardOutput`.
You can then create a `StreamReader` around `StandardOutput` and call `ReadToEnd()`.